# How to use xml with c# form application To get text for Lables Based on user Input from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

i'm working on An win form application in c# 
i wants to add a functionality to my application by which i can change the lable.text on user input basis

i wants to use an xml file so i can set some labels as predefined values that can be changes any time without recompiling application 
or changing language of my application

i have an xml file that i wants to use in my form application

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <product>
    <product_id>1</product_id>
    <product_name>Product 1</product_name>
    <product_price>1000</product_price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <product_id>2</product_id>
    <product_name>Product 2</product_name>
    <product_price>2000</product_price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <product_id>3</product_id>
    <product_name>Product 3</product_name>
    <product_price>3000</product_price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <product_id>4</product_id>
    <product_name>Product 4</product_name>
    <product_price>4000</product_price>
  </product>
```

in my application i have some text for **textbox1,textbox2** And **textbox3** And Lables As
**Lable1,Lable2,Lable3**

on **text change** in **textbox1** I wants to change the value of **lable1.text** According to id 
for example if user enters 1 in textbox1 then lable text should be changed to product 1

As  beginner in c# and programming don't know how to get this working....

Comment: And what have you tried so far ? [**Here a kickstart**](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=c%23+read+xml+site%3Astackoverflow.com) The second result goes straight for a good start by reading a XML file.

Comment: Your xml does not have single root element, so it is not valid. What you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse xml with [Linq to Xml](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=564). On text changed event do the following:

```
int id;
if (!Int32.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out id))
    return; // do nothing if not integer entered

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml_file);
var product = xdoc.Descendants("product")
                  .FirstOrDefault(p => (int)p.Element("product_id") == id);

lable1.Text = (product == null) ? "" : (string)product.Element("product_name");
```

BTW when ask question, always provide code which you already have, to show us where you stuck. Also as I commented under question your xml is invalid, because it have several root elements. Wrap all your product elements into some root, like `<products>`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider dividing your problem in reading and writing XML in C# and look for each answer, also for setting you can use the Settings.Settings file and select User or Application if you want the setting to change or not.

[Build XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-xml-in-c-sharp-code)

[Read XML XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769162/reading-xml-file-in-c-sharp-with-xpathnavigator)

[Ream XML XmlReader, single pass](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548)

[Settings file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)