# get contents from inner xml with xml parsing in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have a service which returns the below xml as string.I am using Xdocument parse method and XmlDocument load methods to convert the string to xml. but i want to parse and get the status and i_numer which i need to use for further processing.can some one point me in right direction or give some hints.below is the xml i am using.

i tried the innerxml property from the Xdocument and XmlDocument which is returning the whole "" element and this is not what i needed.

```
<Report>
    <Incidentreport Company="company1" ID="sample">
       <status i_number="12345678" status="sucessful" />
    </Incidentreport>
</Report>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading XML file in C# with XpathNavigator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769162/reading-xml-file-in-c-sharp-with-xpathnavigator)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
string str = [string of xml goes here];
string i_number = string.Empty;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(str);
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//status");
i_number = node.Attributes["i_number"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SelectSingleNode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectsinglenode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which accept [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parameter to get the target attribute value in one go * :

```
var raw = @"<Report>
    <Incidentreport Company='company1' ID='sample'>
       <status i_number='12345678' status='sucessful' />
    </Incidentreport>
</Report>";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(raw);
var result = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Report/Incidentreport/status/@i_number");
Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DgUHhd)</kbd>**

*) notice how XML attribute can be referenced by using `@attribute_name` syntax in XPath